# How to add specific numbers within an array in php

Tags: php

```
$a = array(2, 6, 24, 16, 7, 10);
```

I know how to add all the numbers using `array_sum()` but if I want to add only the numbers between `2` and `16` how can do that?

This is one of the solution that that I've come up with:

```
    $a = array(2, 6, 24, 16, 7, 10);
    $r = array_slice($a, 0, -2);
    print_r (array_sum($r));
```

Just want to know if there is any other way to get the result.

Comment: *This is one of the solution that that I've come up with:* You just slice the last two array elements and sum them up together. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to find out the summation of the first 4 numbers (2,6,24,16). I didn't mean to find out the summation between a range of numbers..

Comment: You mean you have a start element and an end element which you want to slice out and sum together? (including start and end value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with dynamic bound limits you can extend the initial approach(`array_slice` + `array_sum`) using `array_search` function:

```
$arr = [2, 6, 24, 16, 7, 10];
$a = 10;
$b = 24;

$lowerBound = array_search($a, $arr);
$upperBound = array_search($b, $arr);

if (($low = $lowerBound) > $upperBound) {  // if bounds were confused
    $lowerBound = $upperBound;
    $upperBound = $low;
}
$sum = array_sum(array_slice($arr, $lowerBound, $upperBound - $lowerBound + 1));

print_r($sum);  // 57
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Exactly what I needed..

Comment: How is lowerBound and upperBound values calculated?  Sorry for bothering you again..  I'm actually new to this.

Comment: `array_search` will return the position/key for the specified value. So the condition `if (($low = $lowerBound) > $upperBound)` will compare the numeric positions/keys